# SOAPClient won't attach parameters on method call

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm working to connect via web services to another company using PHP. The connection is successful based on the response from the web service. There is not user validation or password in the process.

The validation of the method is successful too based on the result of print_r($client->__getFunctions()) and print_r($client->__getTypes()) where I can see the information on both cases.

The problems come when the parameters are passing to the method, the request don't have the parameters in the XML body :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:GetToken/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I did different kinds of call with the same result:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('GetToken', array('parameters' => $params));
```

or

```
$response = $client->GetToken(array('parameters' => $params));
```

or

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('GetToken', array($params));
```

or

```
$response = $client->GetToken(array($params));
```

Every try is the same response from the web service because the method is not attaching the parameters to the request

```
[GetTokenResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Token] => 
            [Url] => 
            [StatusCode] => 400
            [StatusDescription] => Value cannot be null.
        )
```

This is my code:

```
Try{
  $wsdlLocation = 'http://webservice.com/Agent.svc?wsdl'; 
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdlLocation,array('location' => $wsdlLocation,
                          'trace' => true,
                      'exceptions' => true
               )
            );

$params = array(
        'Key' => '123456',
        'ReturnUrl' => 'http://Anyweb.com',
        'Name' => 'John Doe',
        'Office' => 'NorhWest',
        'Business' => 'PL',
        'Email' => 'my@email.com',
        );

$response = $client->__soapCall('GetToken', array('parameters' => $params));

print_r($response);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";



} 
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
  trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Also, I tested the web service using the XMLspy. Sending a request from this tool with the same values and parameters. The response in this case was successful. So the issue is not the service on the other company.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some time I found the answer of this. The soap service was waiting for an array named 'request' instead of 'parameter'. This fix all the issue.

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('GetToken', array('request' => $params));
```

I hope this save time to another people.